# Large deviation upper bound in an article

Tags: probability, analysis, large-deviation-theory

[image]

How are $Q(W)$ and $\int W_i d\zeta^\lambda$ eliminated and get the last line?
On page 508 of the article:

Kifer Y. Large deviations in dynamical systems and stochastic processes[J]. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 1990, 321(2): 505-524.